# No output through stereo jack

Tags: arch-linux, audio, kde, alsa, pulseaudio

I cannot get any sound to output through either of my PC's stereo jacks. I do not even hear the typical static when I plug a device in. This is the case even though Phonon displays "built-in audio." I can, however, get sound to output through HDMI. How can I get my stereo jack working?

More details:

- My system is running on an up-to-date Arch Linux
- My sound comes through Phonon on KDE 5. The backend to Phonon is gstreamer, and I have the necessary packages to ensure this integrates with PulseAudio. PulseAudio is installed and running on my system. The system uses ALSA.
- I have tested an audio device on my laptop, and can confirm it works there. My laptop uses a very similar configuration. It should be identical but for the actual hardware.

**EDIT:** This line of lspci's output shows the relevant device: `00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)`

Comment: It sounds like a hardware issue based on the fact that there's no 'typical static' Do those stereo jacks work in other conditions?

Comment: I can't think of any other test cases, as I don't own a license to Windows. I would be surprised if it was a hardware issue, as both the on-board and front-panel jacks would have to not work. But, that isn't out of the question.